# Can you test iphone apps with xcode using wifi?

Tags: iphone, xcode, wifi

I want to be able to test my app while walking around my house, wirelessly.  Can you connect the iphone to xcode thru wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To load and debug you must use the USB interface.

Comment: You can always use a long USB cable or couple of them interconnected.

Comment: USB does have a maximum workable length. In general, it craps out around 14 feet. Some Cat5 extenders can go 30 feet, but not reliably. The protocol + spec just isn't built for it.

Comment: When connecting a device with USB and walking around you always run the risk of dragging the system down from the table.